# About managing Views when using Dependency Injection (MVP pattern)?

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-management, dependency-injection, mvp

Without using DI (Dependency Injection), I can create the View instance myself and I can determine its lifetime myself (create new one each time before showing or just re-show it because it is just hidden).

The problem here involves both DI and the pattern MVP. What I focus on here is the *Presenter* class. By using DI, we can consider *IView* as a dependency used by *Presenter* and DI helps inject that View at runtime (via the Presenter constructor), something like this:

```
public class MyPresenter {
    readonly IView _myView;
    public MyPresenter(IView view){
         _myView = view;
    }
}
```

So as you can see the `IView` is injected just once at the time initializing the `MyPresenter`. That means its `instance` should be maintained along with the lifetime of the `MyPresenter`, otherwise I have to recreate that `IView` instance myself (when needed) which defeats against the use of DI.

Keeping an instance of `IView` along is fine, but the problem might involve here is the memory management. The View may be quickly ready if there is some request showing it, but almost the time it's hidden and still keeps some memory (in some case may be quite large, such as a form showing a large list of objects ...).

Applied in Windows Forms UI tech, I think it is a good practice to `Close` the form to dispose it when not showing. In this case that means the created instance of `IView` won't be usable anymore. So I cannot close it, instead just hide it. What do you think about this?

What if the `MyPresenter` has a lot of dependencies of other `IView`s? I hope you could share some opinion about managing Views in this scenario, so it could involve the right use/design of MVP pattern. Thanks so much!

Comment: Even with Dependency Injection is possible to control lifetime of disposable objects. If you want that consumers of `IView` will be able to control lifetime of view - use `ViewFactory` which can be injected in Presenter and create new instance for `IView` whenever needed. If you want reuse `Forms` instance - you can inject `ViewProvider` which will hold instance of created form and provide it to Presenter whenever asked.

Comment: @Fabio actually I've read about MVP and see that usually `IView` is put in via the presenter's constructor, so it's likely that we need DI here. If using Factory or Provider as you suggest, the `IView` should not be a dependency (because we can freely get or create any one anywhere right in the presenter class) - and of course it should not be some parameter of the presenter's constructor. I'm not so sure if that is a good practice (especially applied on MVP pattern here).

Comment: MVP is about separation Having view's factory/provider as dependency in the presenter will not violate MVP.